# oracle searching word within the input string

Tags: sql, oracle

i have to find out INPUT string word found within the other string that is pipe delimited,i am trying below way but it is surprisingly return 'Y' instead of 'N'.please let me know what i am doing in wrong in below cast statement.

```
    CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_INSTR('TCS|XY|XZ','CS',1,1,1,'i') > 0
      THEN 'Y'
      ELSE 'N'
    END
```

Regards,

Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really no need to use `regexp_instr()` regular expression function. If you just need to know if a particular character literal is part of another character literal, `instr()` function will completely cover your needs:

```
with t1(col) as(
   select 'TCS|XY|XZ' from dual union all
   select 'TAB|XY|XZ' from dual
)
select col
     , case
         when instr(col, 'CS') > 0
         then 'Y'
         else 'N'
       end as Is_Part
 from t1
```

Result:

```
COL        IS_PART
---------  -------
TCS|XY|XZ  Y
TAB|XY|XZ  N
```

**Edit**

---

If you need to take vertical bars into consideration - returning yes only if there is a standalone `CS` sub-string surrounded by vertical bars `|CS|` then yes, you could use `regexp_instr()` regular expression function as follows:

```
 with t1(col) as(
    select 'TCS|XY|XZ|' from dual
  )
  select col
       , case
           when regexp_instr(col, '(\||^)CS(\||$)', 1, 1, 0, 'i') > 0
           then 'YES'
           else 'NO'
         end as res
   from t1
```

Result:

```
COL        RES
---------- ---
TCS|XY|XZ| NO
```

**Note**: If a character literal is dynamic you could use a concatenation operator `||` to form a search pattern `'(\||^)' || <<'character literal', column or variable>> || '(\||$)'`

Comment: THis is not correct,select case
         when instr('TCS', 'CS') > 0
         then 'Y'
         else 'N'
       end as Is_Part FROM DUAL .this is returning Still 'Y'

Comment: @raj Of course it will return yes, because `CS` is part of `TCS`. If there are different criteria of when to return yes and when to return no, you need to state it clearly in the question.

Comment: I want to search exact word.If input string is TCS then only it should return yes.if input string is 'CS' or TC.then it should return No.basically it should check exact word.

Comment: It works great,how to pass character literal dynamically i.e CS

Answer (score 1):

The first field (TCS) contains CS which counts as a match.

If you want to match an entire field you can do like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_INSTR('|' || 'TCS|XY|XZ' || '|' , '\|' || 'CS' || '\|',1,1,1,'i') > 0
  THEN 'Y'
  ELSE 'N'
END
```

Add the delimiter to your query string to "anchor" the search to whole fields. To be able to match the first and last field I also added the delimiter to the searched string.

Comment: THis is also faling.CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_INSTR('|' || 'TCS|XY|XZ' || '|' , '|' || 'CS' || '|',1,1,1,'i') > 0
  THEN 'Y'
  ELSE 'N'
END  returning 'Y'

Comment: I forgot to backslash the `|` in the regex. I fixed it now and tried it, and it returns `N` for `CS` and `Y` for `TCS`.